# Fastest way to iterate over the keys in a hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, benchmarking

I initialized a hash as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11978421/ruby-how-to-iterate-elements-in-a-hash-efficiently) and ran some benchmarks.

```
Benchmark.measure { a = h.keys }
#=>  0.010000   0.000000   0.010000 (  0.019832)
Benchmark.measure { a.each { |k| } }
#=>  0.060000   0.000000   0.060000 (  0.057262)
Benchmark.measure { h.each { |k, v| } }
#=>  0.320000   0.000000   0.320000 (  0.319768)
Benchmark.measure { h.each_key { |k| } }
#=>  0.310000   0.000000   0.310000 (  0.312656)
Benchmark.measure { h.each_pair { |k, v| } }
#=>  0.330000   0.000000   0.330000 (  0.331452)
```

I have thought that turning the hash into an array of keys would be slower, but it's not, and `each_key` has similar performance to `each`. Why is this? What is the best approach?

Comment: What is the best approach? To not worry about it, because it will not be your bottleneck if you have actual code in your block.

Comment: Note that `a.each { |k| }` does something very different from the rest: it does not return keys, but key-value pairs.

Comment: Was my answer what you were looking for?

Comment: Not a fair comparison, as one doesn't invoke a lambda. Should be `Benchmark.measure { h.keys.each { |k| } }`, assuming the point wasn't simply to make an array of keys but rather to iterate through them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [some code on Github](https://github.com/search?p=5&q=%22hash.each%22&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) I can tell you 2 words: It depends. If it's not obvious that your variable name is a hash, then using `.each_pair` will make it obvious (since a hash is a collection of key-value PAIRs). If your variable name mentions 'hash', then this makes sense: `hash.each |key, value|`. It doesn't make sense to do something like `hash.each_pair do |k|` where you pass 1 block argument to `each_pair, it makes the code look confusing.

From analyzing several pages on Github, I'm tempted to conclude that the "best approach" is when using `.each`, you should name your block variables `|key, value|` to make it very obvious you're iterating over a hash (the block arguments will give you a clue it's a hash). When using `.each_pair`, you can be a bit more ambiguous about naming the block arguments like `|my_key_1, my_key_2|` since .each_pair is saying you're iterating over a hash. It's all about looking at your code 1 week (or month) later and being able to INSTANTLY tell what's going on. Unlike with Python, Ruby doesn't have "one right way" to do something.